# Using form_for to add a user to Collaboration model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm building a very basic wiki-style app that uses 3 models: User, Wiki, and Collaboration.  My goal is, via the edit wiki page, a user should be able to add another user to the wiki as a "collaborator".  This is what I have so far:

## Wiki Model

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

has_many :collaborations
has_many :collaboration_users, through: :collaborations, :source => :user 


scope :visible_to, -> (user) { user.role == 'admin' || user.role == 'premium' ? all : where(private: false) }



end
```

## User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

has_many :wikis
has_many :collaborations
has_many :collaboration_wikis, through: :collaborations, :source => :wiki

after_initialize :set_default_role

def set_default_role
  self.role ||= 'standard'
end

def upgrade_to_premium
  self.update_attribute(:role, "premium")
end

def admin?
  role == 'admin'
end

def standard?
  role == 'standard'
end

def premium?
  role == 'premium'
end

end
```

## Collaboration Model

```
class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :wiki
end
```

## My _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for wiki do |f| %>
 <% if wiki.errors.any? %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
   <h4>There are <%= pluralize(wiki.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
   <ul>
     <% wiki.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>
<%= form_group_tag(wiki.errors[:title]) do %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class:'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Wiki name" %>
<% end %> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class:'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Wiki body" %>
  </div>
<% if current_user.role == 'premium' || current_user.role == 'admin' %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :private, class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= f.check_box :private %> Private Wiki
      <% end %>
    </div>

<% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %>
```

My goal is to show a list of all users (if role == premium or admin) with the option to add or delete as a collaborator.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a user to a wiki, as a collaborator, you are creating a collaboration record.  You can do this via the "collaboration_user_ids=" method on a wiki: the association gives you this method, among many others.

For example, you could add user 123, and user 456 as a collaborator to wiki 789 by saying

```
@wiki = Wiki.find(789)
@wiki.collaboration_user_ids = [123, 456]
@wiki.save
```

This will delete or create collaboration records as appropriate, ie delete any collaborations where wiki_id = 789 and user_id NOT IN (123,456), and create a collaboration for user 123 and user 456, if they don't exist already.

So, now we know that we can set the list of collaborating users just by passing an array of their ids to @wiki.collaboration_user_ids, we just need to set up our form to pass this array through as `params[:wiki][:collaboration_user_ids]`, and we can call @wiki.update_attributes(params[:wiki]) as normal.

You could do this by adding this to your form:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Collaborators</p>
    <% collaboration_user_ids = @wiki.collaboration_user_ids %>
    <%# this should more properly use a variable set in your controller rather than User.all - for example you might want to limit the list of possible collaborators according to some condition %>
    <% User.all.each do |user| %>
      <div class="user">
        <%= check_box_tag "wiki[collaboration_user_ids][]", user.id, collaboration_user_ids.include?(user.id) %>
        <%= user.name %> 
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Max, this is such a huge help.

Comment: You're welcome.  I know that with Rails you are often encouraged to dive in and get going asap but i'd strongly recommend reading this page.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Comment: Whoops - just spotted a bug - the name of the check_box_tag needs to be `"wiki[collaboration_user_ids][]"` - the square brackets at the end mean "collect all params with this name into an array" which is what we need.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Actually @Max I seem to be having a problem saving the collaboration_user to the Wiki model, Is my params stopping me?   def wiki_params
    params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private, :collaboration_user_ids)
  end

Comment: No, that `require` call looks ok.  Did you update it after my bug fix (see above)?

Comment: I did, but there's still an error I can't find -- nothing is being added to the Collaboration model